# What's the Best way to store html data in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

Should I create a text field or a different type of field?  Is there anything else I should know before writing the insertion script?  ...Or the select scripts?

Comment: Why do you *want* to store html in your database? Unless you have a very good reason to do so, there are usually better options.

Comment: I'm storing data attached to an email account and it will be more efficient to store an email in the database than to search through a user's email for the message from the sender (using gmail oauth)

Comment: I'm a year late, but it seems like on stackoverflow when you ask "How do I do X" there is always some wise guy who says "Why do you WANT to do X?  There are better options!" but then declines to list any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BLOB` or `TEXT`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CLOB](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/MySQL-CLOB-Large-Object.html) (Character Large Object). Depends upon the length of data you are storing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to store large sections of text in a separate table. This second table only needs an id and a text columns. Do all of your selects on your "meta information" table and then select the text blobs you need from your second table once you have a list of ids.

Comment: It might depend, right? I asked this question recently because I was attempting to store html values in a separate table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135677/insert-php-array-into-two-mysql-tables. Most responses told me to not worry about storing it in a separate table. I'm interested to know if this is correct?