# Insert PHP array into two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am wondering the best way to insert a multidimensional array of values into a database - particularly two tables? I created the following foreach loop which creates a query that will insert all the records into one table:

```
foreach($newPosts as $value) {
            if(!isset($postQuery)) {
                $postQuery = "INSERT INTO posts (primay_key, col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('$value[0]', FROM_UNIXTIME($value[4]), '$value[2]', '$value[1]', '$value[3]')";
            } else {
                $postQuery .= "('$value[0]', FROM_UNIXTIME($value[4]), '$value[2]', '$value[1]', '$value[3]')";
            }
    }
```

I want to store one of the values in a separate table since the value is particularly large and the row is formatted as Longtext. This value is also rarely called upon when querying the database. I am assuming that moving it into a second table will increase the query speed of the first table? Is that correct?

If I move this value into a second table, I want to link the tables with the primary_key from the first table which is an auto-increment value. How do I loop through this multidimensional array and insert my data into both tables, while inserting the primary_key of the first table into the second? I know I can use LAST_INSERT_ID() if I am running each query one at a time. Some updates will insert hundreds of rows though, so I don't want to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "in a separate table since the value is particularly large" That is not a good reason. If it's the same kind of data, it should be in the same table, although you could help us judge the situation by specifying what it is you are inserting.  But if you don't specify the column in you queries, you should not notice a significant delay. Just stay away from `SELECT *`, but instead specify only those columns that you need to select.

Comment: Also, I think you should create the simple version first and see how it performs. You are now thinking about a database redesign and the applyance of bulk inserts, without having tried at all if the simple solution does work fast enough. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, or at least it gives you a lot of uselessly complex, harder to maintain code.

Comment: can you show me your array example ?

Comment: Thanks, @GolezTrol. I think you might be right. Yea, I wasn't sure if that assumption was correct. If I do a SELECT query on the table without the LONGTEXT value - would the speed not be effected? The large value is a string that can max out at 4GB. It probably won't max out very often, but has gone over the 16MB limit for MEDIUMTEXT frequently.

Comment: No, as long as you don't need it, it won't cost much performance. Especially TEXT fields, which are stored in a separate space. The record data itself only contains a reference to that space, so that reference is the only thing that would slow it down, but not any more than adding a small field (like an INT) field that isn't used. Not worth the effort of splitting the table.

Comment: K. I think I'll just go with one table then - and worry about performance later if that becomes an issue. That makes sense though. Thanks, @GolezTrol.

Comment: You may have seen content saved in separate tables. WikiPedia/MediaWiki does that. But that is for a different reason. The content table uses a different table type. The content is stored in a MyISAM table, which is a little faster (especially due to the lack of constraints) and supports FULLTEXT indexes, while the rest of the 'structural data' is stored in InnoDB tables, which support transactions and referential constraints, but not FULLTEXT indexes. Performance was hardly a reason here.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was comparing it to Drupal tables which appear to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am assuming that moving it into a second table will increase the query speed of the first table? Is that correct?

Not necessarily. It's only going to affect performance

- if the large column is indexed (which is unlikely since MySQL limits the size of indexed fields)
- if your queries routinely do full table scans
- if the value is null in a large proportion of cases (more than about a third)

As you say, you lose the benefits of multi-inserts by splitting it into 2 tables. So your only options are, as you suggest, to insert one record at a time and read back the insert id or (with lots of code an complexity) use a sequence generator and preallocate multiple record ids.